# How to requery info in listbox in windows form from another form

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have my main Windows Form with a ListBox that is populated when the program starts. I have a button on the main form to open a "add page". In this new window I can add all the info for the new entry to be added to the ListBox. However, when "add" is clicked and the secondary form closes, I don't do anything to update the ListBox.

Is there a way to call the main form's method, populateCollectionList, from the secondary window? All solutions I've come across seem to have over-complicated the solution.

This is my first time venturing into Windows Forms and I can provide any extra information if necessary.

Main Form:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    String connectionString;
    SqlConnection connection;

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CollectionsManager.Properties.Settings.CollectionsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populateCollectionList();
    }

    private void populateCollectionList()
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Bottlecaps", connection))
        {
            DataTable collectionTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(collectionTable);

            currentItems.ValueMember = "Id";
            currentItems.DisplayMember = "Maker";
            currentItems.DataSource = collectionTable;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmAddItem itemAddPage = new frmAddItem();
        itemAddPage.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Secondary Form ("Add Form"):

```
public partial class frmAddItem : Form
{
    String connectionString;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlConnection connection;

    public frmAddItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\mdfPath;Integrated Security=True");
        connection.Open();
        insertTextFields();
        connection.Close();
        this.Close();
        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO MAKE THE CALL TO REPOPULATE LIST
    }

    private void insertTextFields()
    {
        command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table (SomeParams) VALUES (@someParams)", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", txtField1.Text);
        //....
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", txtField2.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to modify `button1_Click` and call `populateCollectionList` from it when the dialog closes. You can do it and check if the user clicked OK in the dialog:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmAddItem itemAddPage = new frmAddItem();
    if (itemAddPage.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        populateCollectionList();
    }
    itemAddPage.Dispose();
}
```

You can find a similar example on MSDN on [Form.ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) method page.

---

You also need to modify your `populateCollectionList` to refresh the list box. Add the following before you set the data source:

```
currentItems.DataSource = null;
```

Without this the data source won't refresh.

Comment: Hm, but when button1_Click runs, wont the check occur before the user has time to do anything? Would the check be constantly running? I tried it out and it didn't work. But then again, neither did the suggestion from pcowan work. So maybe it has to do with something else.

Comment: @user3750325 ShowDialog will show the dialog as modal so it will block everything else.

Comment: did you set button1's DialogResult to OK?

Comment: No, it was set to None. However changing it to OK didn't fix the problem.

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what is exactly the problem?

Comment: The ListBox isn't repopulated.

Comment: Add `currentItems.DataSource = null;` at the beginning of `populateCollectionList` method. You need it to refresh the list.

Comment: Hm, that didn't do it. I'm thinking of changing this to not use the adapter.

Comment: Not sure then. I prepared a small sample and setting DataSource to null is what is needed to refresh the list box.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a public property to the frmAddItem form that has a reference to the main form:
public frmMain  MainForm;

Then in the frmMain button1_Click you set this property to "this":
itemAddPage.MainForm = this;

Then in frmAddItem  button1_Click you can call the populateCollectionList:
MainForm.populateCollectionList ();

You will need to make the populateCollectionList function public so the frmAddItem can access the method

Comment: Thank you very much! However I think the populateCollectionList may not be the right thing to call again though. Because I tried your solution and Szymon's and they both didn't work. Would I have to clear collectionTable before filling it again?